# How to get real weight / price of label via FedEx API?

Tags: api, fedex

I already have a working FedEx API in production with two services: rate and shipping.

Note that I use:

- My own packages: `"PackagingType": "YOUR_PACKAGING"`
- Almost always I know estimated weight of parcel: `"RequestedPackageLineItems": { "Weight": { "Value": "42" } }`

So, I do rate&buy label with concrete price. But sometimes package exceeds dimensions or weight is changed after buying label – this leads to additional payments and total price for label is different in real life than i receive at the moment of buying label.

**The question is:** How can I get REAL weight and price of sent package?

---

I tried to use tracking service with no luck – API returns old incorrect data of weight and no price.

For example, I know that label 123456789012 was created with 2 lbs of weight with price 9.45$. Later on, weight changed dramatically (to 48 lbs) and price changed to 48.98$. I know that because of talking with real people but request to tracking service of FedEx API says that PackageWeight is still 2 LB and Payments parameter contains only `"Type": "SHIPPER_ACCOUNT"` value and that's all.

---

Okay, I've found out that i need to request invoices because they contain needed information. How to get them? Didn't find any documentation inside PDF for developers.